# Continuity of Probability for Events with Density Greater Than a Threshold

Tags: probability, measure-theory, continuity

I am exploring the conditions (if some exist) under which the function

g(b) = $\mathbb{P}(\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^m: p(\mathbf{x}) \geq b\})$

is continous, where $p$ is a PDF and $\mathbb{P}$ is the probability measure (from the same probability space). I think the conditions should be continuity of $p$ and $p$ having non-zero derivative a.s. but I am struggling to show this, possibly I am missing something major here. I know that $g$ must be monotonous but thats where I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\lim_{y \to b+} \mathbb P(p(X) \ge y) = \mathbb P(p(X) > b)$ and
$\lim_{y \to b-} \mathbb P(p(X) \ge y) = \mathbb P(p(X) \ge b)$, the only issue
is whether there can be $b$ such that $\mathbb P(p(X) = b) > 0$.
I claim this can't happen if $p$ is differentiable with $\nabla p \ne 0$ a.e.
That is:

Suppose $p$ is a function on $\mathbb R^d$ such that for almost every $x$, $p$ is differentiable at $x$ with $\nabla p(x) \ne 0$.  Then for every $b$,
the ($d$-dimensional Lebesgue) measure $m \left(\{x : p(x) = b\}\right) = 0$.

Proof: Let $$B = \{x: p(x) = b,\ p\ \text{differentiable at}\ x,\ \nabla p \ne 0\}$$
If my claim is false, then $B$ has nonzero Lebesgue measure.  By the Lebesgue density theorem, there is $x \in B$ such that for all sufficiently small $r > 0$,
more than half (in terms of Lebesgue measure) of the ball of radius $r$ centred at $x$ is in $B$.  Let $v = \nabla p(x)$, which by assumption is nonzero. Since $p$ is differentiable at $x$, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is $\delta > 0$ such that if $0 < \|y - x\| < \delta$,
$|f(y) - f(x) - v \cdot (y-x)| < \varepsilon\|y-x\|$.  In particular, if $|v \cdot (y-x)| > \varepsilon \|y-x\|$, then $f(y) \ne f(x) = b$.  We can take $\varepsilon$ small enough that $|v \cdot (y-x)| > \varepsilon \|y-x\|$ for $y$ in more than half of any ball centred at $x$, and we are done.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am also suspecting that in this case $g(b)$ is actually bijective/invertible (if we restrict ourselves to the preimage of (0, 1)). Would you have a direction on how to approach that proof?